# How To Export-Import Database in Oracle 11g(Application Express Edition)?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am beginner in Oracle 11g. I have created a database in oracle 11g(Application Express).

I want to export this database with all data(whole workspace) and import this to another computer where I already have installed Oracle.Is there any way to export-import the whole workspace in oracle 11g application express?

Comment: Probalbly better suite for dba.stackexchange.com, but have a loook at ´exp´and ´imp´ utilities.

Comment: In Utilities, i found only data export-import feature but didn't find anything where I can export the whole database.

Comment: You're mixing Application Express (i.e. your workspace) with the database schema. Which do you want to export/import?

Comment: I want to export/import my database schema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a full database export/import use

```
exp user@DB FULL=Y FILE=PATH_TO_DUMPFILE
imp user@DB FULL=Y FILE=PATH_TO_DUMPFILE
```

The user must have EXP_FULL_DATABASE resp IMP_FULL_DATABASE role (or something equivalent, like DBA). DB is your database (e.g. XE, if you have expreess edition)

Comment: sql command line doesn't recognise the exp command.As I am beginner in Oracle.please help me with detail steps. thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't execute them in sqlplus but on OS command line.

Comment: For anyone finding this question now, there are [two new commands](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g) for exporting and importing entire databases.  `expdp user@DB full=Y dumpfile=PATH_TO_DUMPFILE` and `impdp user@DB full=Y dumpfile=PATH_TO_DUMPFILE`.