# How to manually export all data from an Oracle Database (not using Developer export functions)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to export all the data a user has (tables with their data, triggers, functions, packages etc) using a script in Oracle Database Developer. I can not use the `export data` functions from the application, I need to write a script for that.

Is there any documentation regarding exporting data to files manually? Writing everything into a .txt file would be fine.

PS: it is a school assignment so the only way to do this is writing a script in Oracle Database Developer.

Comment: Use expdp utility. Please refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL824

Comment: Use the [export (`exp`)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#g1070082), [export data pump (`expdp`)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL200) or [recovery manager (`rman`)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmquick.htm#BRADV89346) utilities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Export-Import Database in Oracle 11g(Application Express Edition)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626970/how-to-export-import-database-in-oracle-11gapplication-express-edition)

Comment: I need to write the export functions in a script.

Comment: why does it need to be a script? we've already built these things for you. to not use them brings in several hazards, which you will find as you start on this exercise. Getting megabytes of data out using a script will be fine, but your script will run for days if not weeks once you get to a larger systems, and your output will be unmanageable.

Comment: It's a school assignment.

Comment: You can write a script to call dbms_metadata - that will generate the DDL for your objects.

Comment: Your assignment needs to have a disclaimer that your scripts will not be able to manage dependencies between objects, as this is one of the complexities that exp/imp(dp) manages. There are many DDL scripts available on the net.

Comment: I think you need to google about DBMS_DATAPUMP